# I want one record in crystal report but retrieving all the records

Tags: vba, crystal-reports-8.5

I am vb 6 programmer. I have two tables one is 'Admissions' & second is 'Exams'.

Admissions                           !           Exams

ID   | Name  | F_Name  |            !         S_NO   |  ID  | Month |  Year |
36   | Usman | Aziz    |             !     1     |  38  | 02    |  2012 |
37   | Kami  | Wali    |            !      2     |  38  | 08    |  2011 |
38   | Jabbar| Abbas   |             !     3     |  37  | 07    |  2013 |

I have written the query as.

```
"select A.Name,A.F_Name,E.ID,E.Month,E.Year _
     From Admissions A INNER JOIN Exams E ON Admissions.ID=Exams.ID
     where Exams.ID=38 AND Exams.Month=08"
```

But the crystal reports shows two records that are 
38 Jabbar Abbas 02 2012
38 Jabbar Abbas 08 2011
I want the crystal report to display only one specific record so how should I do?

Comment: Admissions ! Exams ID | Name | F_Name | ! S_NO | ID | Month | Year | 36 | Usman | Aziz | ! 1 | 38 | 02 | 2012 | 37 | Kami | Wali | ! 2 | 38 | 08 | 2011 | 38 | Jabbar| Abbas | ! 3 | 37 | 07 | 2013 |

Comment: I have two tables connected with one another with field 'ID'. Here i want to display in crytal report a specific Exams table 38 ID record while there are two records of ID 38. so how write a query i wrote a but do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad, I am not sure what you are trying to do here, you need to better display your table.

On another note, some points:

1. If you are taking Input from a user, you are supposed to use Parameters.
2. Try to retrieve everything from the database, and then use Formula field to suppress the records.

Comment: I have two tables connected with one another with field 'ID'. Here i want to display in crytal report a specific Exams table 38 ID record while there are two records of ID 38. so how write a query i wrote a but do not work

Comment: Write a query like this: Select A.*, B.* from Table1 as A Inner Join Table2 as B On A.ID = B.ID